# How to add delete cascade constraint in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, cascading-deletes

I have 2 tables.Table A have columns as (aid, name,depart) where aid is primary key.

Table B has (aid1,aid2,aid3,created_by) where aid1 is the primary_key. aid1, aid2 and aid3 all are primary key of Table A

I want to delete a record in Table B i.e aid1 and simultaneously with delete cascade all three records in TABLE A should be deleted. My doubt here is where should I put the delete cascade constraint. I know that in parent child relationship we need to put delete cascade on the child table so that when parent is deleted, child entities are also deleted but in this scenario I dont understand where I should put delete cascade

Comment: Cascading deletes go in the other direction.  When the *primary* key is deleted, dependent rows are also deleted.  What you want to do doesn't make sense, because other rows might reference the same values in `A`.

Comment: This type of design could easily result in a single row in the child table being deleted resulting in **every** row in both the parent and child tables being deleted. I very much doudt that is your intent.

Comment: What you could attempt is to create an instead-of-delete-trigger on table B that deletes the record in B nd thern tries to delete the 3 records in table A, what can fail(use error handling), since other records could reference them. see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251786/solving-on-delete-cascade-cycles-with-triggers-on-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Cascading a table will be on the child table. You have to set this on your child table when creating or after creating the child table.
E.g

```sql
CREATE TABLE schools (
  id int auto_increment primary key not null,
  schoolname varchar(191) not null
);

CREATE TABLE students(
  id int auto_increment primary key not null,
  studentname varchar(191) not null,
  school_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES students(id) ONDELETE CASCADE
);
```

or
You can as well alter the table by running this command.

```sql
ALTER TABLE childTable
ADD FOREIGN KEY (childTableParentTableColumn) REFERENCES parentTable(parentTableColumn);
```